# How to have a wordpress site per year i.e. /2016 /2017 /2018

Tags: php, wordpress

Context:

We did a website for a client for a big event, 2017 edition. It has guests speakers, sponsors, etc. as posts. But they were all for 2017 and the event is over. Now the 2018 edition is coming up. On the website should be only 2018 sponsors. But it would be nice to still be able to visit the 2017 version, with 2017 sponsors, etc. Ideally: http://mywebsite.com/2017/ and of course for many years to come.

How to go about this?

Option 1:

Obviously we could copy the whole website in a 2017 folder. It would be simple BUT how about in 10 years ? There will be 10 wordpress installs ? That's a lot of data and databases to maintain and plugins to update.

Option 2:

Have a post category 2017, 2018, etc. So to have 2018 showing up, we add array( 'cat' => '2018') to the loop in the page.php, but how to show 2017 ?

Any other options are welcomed. Not looking for specific code but more the logic on how to go about this.

TL:DR how to have a different edition of the same website every year and have /2017/ in the URL